# Getting exit value: -1,073,741,571 with simple code to calculate nth moment

Tags: c, eclipse, memory, physics, exit-code

I'm having issues with this code to calculate the nth moment (like center of mass, would be the 1st moment) of an array of random numbers.  I'm coding in C in eclipse, this error also occurs when i try to compile with gcc.  When I run the code for N<1000000, the code runs fine.  But when I try to input a higher value of N, like 1000000 or 1 million, the code gives me the exit value -1,073,741,571, and does not print out the moments like it should.  I think it has something to do with memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//here we import the three libraries
//we start our main function
int main ()
{
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    //setbuf disables buffering so print statements print properly
    int i,N;

    unsigned int seed;
    double first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth,firsttot,secondtot,thirdtot,fourthtot,fifthtot,sixthtot;
    //here we declare the vars to be used
    printf("\nEnter number of iterations and seed");
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%i %u", &N, &seed);
    srand(seed);
    //asks user for input, scans the input, and takes the seed to set a starting point for the rand() function called in the for loop
    //since my R array depends on the user, i declare the array here, after the user inputs the size of the array
    double R[N];
    for (i=0;i<N;i=i+1)
    {
        R[i]=(double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        //printf("%12.8lf \n",R[i]);
    }

    //the for loop sets R equal to a random value using our seed with (double)rand()
    printf("\n");
    //here, we have for loops to add up the individual nth moments for each point of the array
    firsttot = 0.0;
    for (i=0;i<N;i=i+1)
    {
        firsttot = firsttot + pow(R[i],1);
    }
    secondtot = 0.0;
    for (i=0;i<N;i=i+1)
    {
        secondtot = secondtot + pow(R[i],2);
    }
    thirdtot = 0.0;
    for (i=0;i<N;i=i+1)
    {
        thirdtot= thirdtot + pow(R[i],3);
    }
    fourthtot = 0.0;
    for (i=0;i<N;i=i+1)
    {
        fourthtot = fourthtot + pow(R[i],4);
    }

    fifthtot = 0.0;
    for (i=0;i<N;i=i+1)
    {
        fifthtot = fifthtot + pow(R[i],5);
    }
    sixthtot = 0.0;
    for (i=0;i<N;i=i+1)
    {
        sixthtot = sixthtot + pow(R[i],6);
    }

    //now, we take the actual nth moment by dividing each total by N;
    first = firsttot/N;
    second = secondtot/N;
    third = thirdtot/N;
    fourth = fourthtot/N;
    fifth = fifthtot/N;
    sixth = sixthtot/N;
    printf("\nThe first moment is:   %lf",first);
    printf("\nThe second moment is:   %lf",second);
    printf("\nThe third moment is:   %lf",third);
    printf("\nThe fourth moment is:   %lf",fourth);
    printf("\nThe fifth moment is:   %lf",fifth);
    printf("\nThe sixth moment is:   %lf",sixth);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Negative value due to integer overflow

Comment: didn't the rustin say 1000000 (1 million)? what you posted says 10000000 (10 million). Either way, a 32-bit number wouldn't overflow for 10 million (32-bit ints can store 4billion+)

Comment: though I do suspect this is likely related to overflow as you suggest.

Comment: actually I just noticed that the R array is a variable length array based around the N value. I could see that blowing the stack for sufficiently high values of N

Comment: Is there any way to make it work with an array for large values of N?  I need to be able to compute with N = 1,000,000, and it only works for values of N around 10,000

Comment: yup! left an answer saying as much, but use `malloc` instead of a stack array.

Comment: `int` should not exceed 32767...

Answer (score 1):

In your code you construct an array on the stack of size `N`: `int R[N]`

I suspect this is causing stack overflow for sufficiently large values of N.
Can you see if the behavior reproduces if you replace your line `int R[N]` with `int* R = malloc(sizeof(*R) * N);`

using malloc will heap allocate your `R` array instead of using stack allocation which will avoid the possible stack overflow

Comment: It worked!  Thank you for the help, I didn't know about malloc, but that definitely solved the problem.